# Helm3: Create .properties files recursively in Configmap

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Below are files that I have:
`users-values.yaml` file :

```
users:
  - foo
  - baz
```

`other-values.yaml` file:

```
foo_engine=postgres
foo_url=some_url
foo_username=foofoo
baz_engine=postgres
baz_url=some_url
baz_username=bazbaz
```

`config.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-catalog
data:
  {{- range $user := .Values.users }}
  {{ . }}: |
    engine.name={{ printf ".Values.%s_engine" ($user) }}
    url={{ printf ".Values.%s_url" ($user) }}
    username={{ printf".Values.%s_username" ($user) }}
  {{- end }}
```

`deployment-coordinator.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-coordinator"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-coordinator"
spec:
  replicas: 1
...
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-coordinator"
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: test-catalog
...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: "/etc/config"
```

Then, I do a `helm install test mychart`.

When I `exec` into the pod, and `cd` to `/etc/config`, I expect to see `foo.properties` and `baz.properties` files in there, and each file looks like:

```
  foo.properties: |
    engine.name=postgres
    url=some_url
    username=foofoo
```

```
  baz.properties: |
    engine.name=postgres
    url=some_url
    username=bazbaz
```

The answer from Pawel below solved the error I got previously

```
unexpected bad character U+0022 '"' in command
```

But, the files are still not created in the `/etc/config` directory.
So, I was wondering if it's even possible to create the .properties files using helm range as I mentioned in my `config.yaml` file above.

The reason I wanted to do it the below way is because I have more than 10 users to create .properties files on, not just foo and baz. Just thought it'll be easier if I can do a for loop on it if possible.

```
data:
  {{- range $user := .Values.users }}
  {{ . }}: |
    engine.name={{ printf ".Values.%s_engine" ($user) }}
    url={{ printf ".Values.%s_url" ($user) }}
    username={{ printf".Values.%s_username" ($user) }}
  {{- end }}
```

Comment: Put a space between `printf` and `"`.

Comment: thank you, that took care of the error, but the files aren't created still.

Comment: Do you have any new errors? Also - how exactly do you generate files? Please include commands and step by step walkthrough. I have a hard time replicating your issue.

Comment: I updated my question. I didn't have any new errors after I fixed the space between `printf` and `"`. The .properties files are just not created when I `exec` into the pod.

Comment: What does `kubectl get configmap test-catalog -o yaml` show?  (Or, equivalently, the ConfigMap output from `helm template test mychart`?)  How are the two files you list brought into the chart as settings?